# c++ reference members: good practice?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm working on this code where there are some parameters (let's say A and B) that need to be updated depending on each other's value. Each update requires a separate class and the full algorithm is contained in another class, for example:

```
class MyClass {
  AUpdater aUpdater;
  BUpdater bUpdater;

  void doStuff(int numTimes) {
    for (int i=0; i<numTimes; i++) {
      aUpdater.update();
      bUpdater.setParams(aUpdater.get_a());
      bUpdater.update();
      aUpdater.setParams(bUpdater.get_b());
    }   
  }
}

class AUpdater {
 protected:
  A a;
  B paramb;
 public:
  void update();
  A get_a();
 }

 class BUpdater {
  protected: 
   B b;
   A parama;
  public:
   void update();
   B get_b();
 }
```

Now I think that using references for A and B in class A and class B would speed up the code as there would not be the need to call getters and setters method at each iteration.

However I read that having reference parameters in classes might not be a good idea and since I'm quite new to c++ I was wandering what is the "right" code design for this specific task.

In particular, which object should have the "original" A and "original" B? Should they be in MyClass?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use of const reference **const A& get_a()** helps?

Comment: *Now I think that using references for A and B in class A and class B would speed up the code as there would not be the need to call getters and setters method at each iteration.* This is not how performance tuning works. Inlining setters is standard procedure for compilers. If you want to talk about performance you must profile and benchmark, not guess or go by what looks fast.

Comment: @nwp ok thanks, what about memory overhead? Having A and B as references would imply having only one object A and only one object B, while as of now each class has its copy. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's complicated. Usually you can trade time for memory and memory for time. But then caches kick in and more memory suddenly means slower execution. This also depends on how much other stuff you have in memory. Either you care and measure and pick the faster one or you delay such micro-optimizations until it starts to matter. In my experience it never does.

Comment: "Each update requires a separate class" Really? What's wrong with `void ::UpdateA(A &a, const B & b)` and `void ::UpdateB(const A & a, B & b)`?

Comment: @Caleth, this is just an example, in reality I have a dozen of parameters to update and each update is ~50-100 lines of code

Comment: I don't see a reason to have an `AUpdater`, you aren't writing Java. More likely you should extract some classes from those dozen parameters and how they update.